# How to get Git(Lab) release notes (not message) from tags

Tags: git, gitlab

I would like to retrieve all the `release notes` that you can specify on a new `tag` or edited afterwards.

[image]

---

These are actual my `tags` on `gitlab`:

[image]

I actually got the following script (`changelog.sh`) to generate my changelog

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Author:Dominic Jonas
echo CHANGELOG > changelog.txt
echo ---------------------- >> changelog.txt
git for-each-ref --sort='*authordate' --format='%(tag)' refs/tags |tac |grep -v '^$' | while read TAG ; do
    echo
    if [ $NEXT ];then
        echo [$NEXT]
        git cat-file -p $NEXT | tail -n +6
        echo
    fi
    NEXT=$TAG
done >> changelog.txt
```

---

and the `changelog.txt` output (from script)

```
CHANGELOG
----------------------


[v2.6.0]
- added new configuration entries for aoi
- added possibility to pre-load aoi plans
- added new func to show referenced components in recipes

[v2.5.2]
- siehe v2.5.1 (vergessen zu mergen)

[v2.5.1]
- automatisch switch between modus and haproplace
```

As you can see on `v2.5.2` and `v2.5.1` I got the `message` and not the `release notes`. How can I get the `release notes` from `gitlab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab release notes are stored in the database, not in the Git repo while the message is stored in the Git repo. This is why you're able to get the message but not the release notes in the script you have.

The only way you could get release notes would be to use the GitLab API - [Releases API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/#get-a-release-by-a-tag-name). In the payload `description` is the attribute that corresponds to 'Release notes' in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

As @Drew Blessing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57793669/6229375) already said, you have to use the `GitLab API` in order to get this information.

I made a script which is automatically fetching this informations: https://github.com/dojo90/gitlab-release-notes